# CSS folder is not loading in my browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

[image]

This is my folder path but when I run server.js which is my nodejs file I'm unable to load CSS folder.

In my browser : CSS folder is not loading..

[image]

Comment: Could you send the error from the developer console?

Comment: How are you serving it? How are you requesting it?